# select cell in UICollectionView not work

Tags: uicollectionview

In my main view controller, I have a **UICollectionView** (created by using the IB). And:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NSLog(@"Cell clicked....%d",[indexPath row]);
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


ChildView *calendar = [[ChildView alloc] initWithDate:newDate];
calendar.delegate         = self;
[cell.contentView addSubview:calendar];

return cell;

}
```

If I touch outside the bounds of the child view, I get the event. If I touch inside the cell, where the child view is, no event is trapped in `didSelectCellAtRowIndex`.
Why?

Comment: It seems that if I implement touchBegan inside the Custom UIView, didSelectItemAtIndex will not be called. Removing any touch related method works.

Comment: you fix your problem?

Answer (score 3):

The collection view handles its touches internally, so any touch handlers or gesture recognizers on your views will take precedence.

Comment: This was helpful to me! Just realized I had a tap gesture recognizer on a higher view controller :)